# Unwanted slash in string literal

Tags: c#, string, filenames, string-literals

I'm trying to pass a filename to a cmd prompt. Ive looked various places but cant seem to find the answer - I'm sure its simple.

My string is built like so:

```
string cmd = string.Format(@" -u{0} -p{1} -h{2} -P{3} {4} < ""{5}""",
                user, pass, server, port, database, filename);
```

However the result is a string like so:

```
-uuser -ppass -hhost -P1234 database < \"C:\\my file.sql\"
```

How do i remove the \ before and after the filename? Its causing the process to run with a file cannot be found error.

My string needs to be:

```
-uuser -ppass -hhost -P1234 database < "C:\\my file.sql"
```

**EDIT:
OK, disregard this question.. there is something else goind on with process.start();**

Comment: How are you viewing the contents of the string? Some visualizers will escape the quotes. View it using the text visualizer, not the tooltip or the immediate window.

Comment: This is actually passed into the cmd window where I am viewing it. And yes it appears the same in the Text Visualizer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried running the following code in Visual Studio and the output is correct. You are most likely looking at the debugging information in Visual Studio which will escape the quotes.

```
string cmd = string.Format(@" -u{0} -p{1} -h{2} -P{3} {4} < ""{5}""",
    "Test", "Test2", "server", "1337", "db", "C:\\filename.sql");

Console.WriteLine(cmd);
Console.Read();
```

The actual output is  `-uTest -pTest2 -hserver -P1337 db < "C:\filename.sql"`